# "Undefined method PDO::execute()" despite using prepare

Tags: php, oop, pdo, undefined

This code has been working before, but I recently added a database class. I get the instance and connection from it:

```
           $connection = MYSQLDatabase::getInstance()->getConnection();
            $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users etc etc.......
            $insertArray = $connection->execute(array(
                ":username" => $_POST["username"]
            ));
```

**getInstance()** returns the database instance. **getConnection()** returns the connection property which contains:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

So the error occurs when doing **$connection->execute** despite that $connection contains the database object, the connection, and the prepared statement.
How can this be?

Comment: *" but I recently added a database class"* - then post that class. visit http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php and put in hard coded credentials. If that works, then it's the way you've set up your connection. see also http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and check for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable to store your prepared statement then execute that.

```
$connection = MYSQLDatabase::getInstance()->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users etc etc.......");
$insertArray = $statement->execute(array(
    ":username" => $_POST["username"]
));
```

Comment: Yes, now I get it. Thanks!